# Why does "activator start" fail with "Bad application path"?

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator

I've created an application in Play Framework using `activator new`.

Upon `activator start` this application it's giving me the following error:

```
Bad application path: -Dhttp.port=9000
```

[image]

How to solve the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391014/play-2-2-application-crashes-on-heroku

Comment: i have already visited the link... there is not my situation to solve. thanks for the link :)

Comment: FYI, there's also an open [github issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3081).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but only after creating a binary distribution using the dist command from the activator when I try to run the play application using the Bat file and add some configuration parameters I go the same error.

Here is the error I am getting

```
Bad application path: -Dhttp.port=9009
```

So the way I solve it is by editing the Bat file. I manually add all the configuration parameters into the APP_MAIN_CLASS and before the "play.core.server.NettyServer"

something like:

```
set "APP_MAIN_CLASS= -DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Dhttp.port=9009 play.core.server.NettyServer"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, then I know you can include a PROJECTNAME_config.txt file and put all your settings in there, like this:

[image]

I'm using Play 2.3.6 in this example.